# Error on code in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made this code for SQL Server to select how many times the rider "AsdoVolante" came first in the first semester of 2017. But it does not work. What could be wrong?

```
SELECT P.Data, Nm.Nome, epp.PosicaoFinal
FROM Prova P, Piloto Nm, EquipaParticipaProva epp
WHERE epp.PosicaoFinal = (SELECT PosicaoFinal FROM EquipaParticipaProva where PosicaoFinal = 1)
HAVING Nm.Nome ='AsdoVolante' AND P.Data BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-06-30';
```

Tables created in SQL Server for the code:

```
CREATE TABLE Carro(
IdCarro INT NOT NULL,
Marca VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Modelo VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (IdCarro));

CREATE TABLE Piloto(
IdPiloto INT NOT NULL,
Nome VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Morada VARCHAR(50),
Telefone INT,
PRIMARY KEY (IdPiloto));

CREATE TABLE Equipa(
IdEquipa INT NOT NULL,
Nome VARCHAR(20),
Morada VARCHAR(50),
Telefone INT,
PRIMARY KEY (IdEquipa));

CREATE TABLE Patrocinador(
IdPatrocinador INT NOT NULL,
Nome VARCHAR(20)NOT NULL,
Morada VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (IdPatrocinador));

CREATE TABLE Prova(
IdProva INT NOT NULL,
Nome VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Local VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Data DATE NOT NULL,
NrVoltas INT NOT NULL,
MelhorTempo TIME,
PRIMARY KEY (IdProva));

CREATE TABLE EquipaParticipaProva(
IdInscricao INT NOT NULL,
IdEquipa INT NOT NULL,
IdCarro INT NOT NULL,
IdPiloto INT NOT NULL,
IdProva INT NOT NULL,
PosicaoFinal INT,
TempoFinal TIME,
FOREIGN KEY (IdProva) REFERENCES Prova(IdProva),
FOREIGN KEY (IdCarro) REFERENCES Carro(IdCarro),
FOREIGN KEY (IdPiloto) REFERENCES Piloto(IdPiloto),
FOREIGN KEY (IdEquipa) REFERENCES Equipa(IdEquipa),
PRIMARY KEY (IdInscricao));

CREATE TABLE Voltas(
IdVolta INT NOT NULL,
IdInscricao INT NOT NULL,
PosicaoRelativa INT NOT NULL,
TempoVolta TIME,
FOREIGN KEY (IdInscricao) REFERENCES EquipaParticipaProva(IdInscricao),
PRIMARY KEY (IdVolta, IdInscricao));

CREATE TABLE PatrocinadorOficial(
IdPatrocinador INT NOT NULL,
IdProva INT NOT NULL,
Valor MONEY NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (IdProva) REFERENCES Prova(IdProva),
PRIMARY KEY (IdPatrocinador, IdProva));

CREATE TABLE PatrocinadorNaoOficial(
IdPatrocinador INT NOT NULL,
IdProva INT NOT NULL,
Valor MONEY NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (IdProva) REFERENCES Prova(IdProva),
PRIMARY KEY (IdPatrocinador, IdProva));

CREATE TABLE Mecanico(
IdMecanico INT NOT NULL,
Nome VARCHAR(20),
Morada VARCHAR(50),
Telefone INT,
PRIMARY KEY (IdMecanico));

CREATE TABLE Afinacao(
IdAfinacao INT NOT NULL,
IdMecanico INT NOT NULL,
IdEquipa INT NOT NULL,
TipoAfinacao VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
TempoDespendido TIME,
Data DATE NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (IdEquipa) REFERENCES Equipa(IdEquipa),
FOREIGN KEY (IdMecanico) REFERENCES Mecanico(IdMecanico),
PRIMARY KEY (IdAfinacao));
```

Inserts created in SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO Carro
VALUES (1, 'Nissan', 'Skyline');

INSERT INTO Carro
VALUES (2, 'Subaru', 'Impreza');

INSERT INTO Carro
VALUES (3, 'Mitsubishi', 'Evolution');

INSERT INTO Piloto
VALUES (111, 'Piloto 1', 'Castelo Branco', 111111111);

INSERT INTO Piloto
VALUES (112, 'Piloto 2', 'Castelo Branco', 111111112);

INSERT INTO Piloto
VALUES (113, 'JaGanhou', 'Lisboa', 111111113); 

INSERT INTO Piloto
VALUES (114, 'AsdoVolante', 'Lisboa', 111111114);

INSERT INTO Piloto
VALUES (115, 'AsdoPedal', 'Beja', 111111115);

INSERT INTO Piloto
VALUES (116, 'Pelo Nome', 'Santarém', 111111116);

INSERT INTO Equipa
VALUES (001, 'OsAtolados', 'Castelo Branco', 272722123);

INSERT INTO Equipa
VALUES (002, 'Sparco', 'Lisboa', 212312432); 

INSERT INTO Equipa
VALUES (003, 'ESTeam', 'Castelo Branco', 272343573);

INSERT INTO Prova
VALUES (010, 'RallycrossCB', 'Castelo Branco', '2017-02-02', 4, '00:04:20');

INSERT INTO Prova
VALUES (11, 'RallyLels', 'Bells', '2017-03-04', 10, '00:10:00');

INSERT INTO Prova
VALUES (12, 'Rally Portugal', 'Fafe', '2017-05-15', 2, '00:15:00');

INSERT INTO Prova
VALUES (13, 'Rally CB', 'Castelo Branco', '2017-01-01', 2, '00:15:00');

INSERT INTO Prova
VALUES (14, 'Rally Norte', 'Porto', '2017-02-02', 2, '00:30:00');

INSERT INTO EquipaParticipaProva
VALUES (441, 002, 3, 113, 010, 1, '00:04:00');

INSERT INTO EquipaParticipaProva
VALUES (442, 1, 2, 111, 11, 1, '00:10:00');

INSERT INTO EquipaParticipaProva
VALUES (443, 3, 1, 112, 10, 1,'00:05:00' );

INSERT INTO EquipaParticipaProva
VALUES (444, 3, 1, 114, 12, 1,'00:15:00' );

INSERT INTO EquipaParticipaProva
VALUES (445, 3, 1, 114, 13, 1,'00:15:00' );

INSERT INTO EquipaParticipaProva
VALUES (446, 3, 2, 114, 14, 5,'01:00:00' );

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (1, 443, 1, '00:01:15');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (2, 443, 1, '00:01:15');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (3, 443, 3, '00:01:15');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (1, 444, 1, '00:07:30');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (2, 444, 1, '00:07:30');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (1, 445, 1, '00:07:30');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (2, 445, 1, '00:07:30');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (1, 446, 5, '00:30:00');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (2, 446, 5, '00:30:00');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (4, 443, 3, '00:01:15');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (1, 441, 1, '00:01:00' );

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (2, 441, 1, '00:01:20');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (3, 441, 1, '00:01:00');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (4, 441, 1, '00:01:00');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (5, 441, 1, '00:01:00');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (6, 441, 1, '00:01:00');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (7, 441, 1, '00:01:00');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (8, 441, 1, '00:01:20');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (9, 441, 1 ,'00:00:30');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (10, 441, 1, '00:01:30');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (1, 441, 10, 2, '00:00:45');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (2, 441, 10, 2, '00:01:00');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (3, 441, 10, 2, '00:01:00');

INSERT INTO Voltas
VALUES (4, 441, 10, 2, '00:01:15');

INSERT INTO PATROCINADOR
VALUES(921, 'IPCB', 'Av da Talagueira');

INSERT INTO PATROCINADOR
VALUES(922, 'Bells Bar', 'Praceta Qualquer Coisa');

INSERT INTO PATROCINADOR
VALUES(923, 'MonsterEnergy', 'USA');

INSERT INTO PATROCINADOR
VALUES(924, 'Sical', 'Lisboa');

INSERT INTO PATROCINADOROFICIAL
VALUES(923, 010, 10000);

INSERT INTO PATROCINADOROFICIAL
VALUES(921, 11, 8000);

INSERT INTO PATROCINADORNAOOFICIAL
VALUES(920, 010, 5000);

INSERT INTO PATROCINADORNAOOFICIAL
VALUES(922, 11, 3000);

INSERT INTO PATROCINADORNAOOFICIAL
VALUES(924, 10, 6000);

INSERT INTO MECANICO
VALUES(333, 'Zacarias','Leiria',933628487);

INSERT INTO MECANICO
VALUES(334, 'Zé', 'Bragança', 963628487);

INSERT INTO MECANICO
VALUES(335, 'Luís', 'Lisboa', 913628487);

INSERT INTO AFINACAO
VALUES(20, 333, 001, 'Travões', '1:00:00', '2017-02-03');

INSERT INTO AFINACAO
VALUES(21, 334, 002, 'Luzes', '00:15:00', '2017-02-03');

INSERT INTO AFINACAO
VALUES(22, 335, 003, 'Travoes', '1:00:00', '2017-02-01');
```

Comment: How does it not work? Any error? Unexpected output? Share sample input data and expected result of the query.

Comment: This is the error: Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 364
Column 'Piloto.Nome' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 364
Column 'Prova.Data' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 364
Column 'Prova.Data' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: You have lot of problem areas in query which can be improved. But to start with Replace HAVING with AND.

Comment: I replaced HAVING with AND as you suggested @ChetanRanpariya . This was the new error now: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 304
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Replace `(SELECT PosicaoFinal FROM EquipaParticipaProva where PosicaoFinal = 1)` with `1`.

Comment: Now it worked but it gives me repeated values. Instead of giving me the values of the races that AsdoVolante was in first place, gives me the laps. @ChetanRanpariya . I'm going to put the Tables for you. Maybe it can help.

Comment: The table names don't make much sense. Its about what data they store and what is your logic to retrieve the expected result. You also need to share some sample data which you are trying to query and what is the logic you are trying to put in the query.

Comment: I'm going to put the inserts in the question. @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: And what is the logic of `select how many times the rider "AsdoVolante" came first in the first semester of 2017`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT P.Data, Nm.Nome, epp.PosicaoFinal
FROM Prova P, Piloto Nm, EquipaParticipaProva epp
WHERE epp.PosicaoFinal **IN** (SELECT PosicaoFinal FROM EquipaParticipaProva where PosicaoFinal = 1)
HAVING Nm.Nome ='AsdoVolante' AND P.Data BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-06-30';
```

It will work for you